# Creating tweaks/apps/scripts for Jailbroken iPhone's

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a simple way to write my own little tweaks for a Jailbroken iPhone? I don't have a MAC, I have Windows.

Is there a way to write tweaks that I can transfer to my iPhone using a Windows computer? What tools are needed? Languages? Are there any helpful resources you know of that may help in this process?

I have spent a long time trying to find a way to do this but all I ever find are links to Linux Bash resources and MAC stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to write tweaks that I can transfer to my iPhone using a Windows computer? What tools are needed?

There's a [cross-toolchain from Windows to iOS](http://code.google.com/p/mingw-and-ndk/downloads/detail?name=multiarch-darwin11-cctools127.2-gcc42-5666.3-llvmgcc42-2336.1-Windows-120614.7z&can=2&q=), but if you haven't worked with any Unix-based system, you'll feel a pain in your <s>*ss</s> [insert arbitrary part of body here].

So yes, there is a way. You don't technically need a Mac for developing applications and tweaks for a jailbroken iPhone.

Also, to obtain reverse engineered classes and header files with which you can examine the internals of an application, you want to use the `class-dump` (or `class-dump-z`) utility.

To actually hook or modify the behavior of an application, you'll most probably use [MobileSubstrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate).

> Languages?

C (you have to master it before trying to mess with the operating system, because if you don't, you **will** screw up your iPhone) and Objective-C (after having learnt C, you should learn Objective-C and the Cocoa Touch API to understand what and how is done in iOS in general). Perhaps a breath of C++ wouldn't do any harm so it's worth learning it too.

> Are there any helpful resources you know of that may help in this process?

There are, definitively. Google "C tutorial", "Objective-C tutorial" and "mobile substrate tweak tutorial".

Comment: Thank you very much @H2CO3 - you just helped relieve a bit of that pain in my [arbitrary part of body].

Comment: @jAsOn Be careful though - it may not be that easy as it might sound. It took me almost half a year to be comfortable with all this.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings :) I'll try to be as careful as possible. I know C++, but haven't touched any of the others yet so it will be a little scary ... for a long while :P

Comment: No worries. I was waiting for the timer to run out so I could accept :)